# Invalid Bson Field $set or $inc with upsert true throwing exception

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, vert.x

```
{"updateOne":{
    "filter":{"_id":"0"},
    "update":{"$set":{"errorCodeCount":1}},
    "upsert":true
}}
```

While calling bulkWrite method in java vertx, it's giving the exception
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name $set`

Answer (score 0):

Your update field value is not interpreted as a new document. I think the easiest way would be to separately define the filter document and the update document.